# Append an html to parent of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code :

```
<div class="time-widget">
    <select id="p_h_0_startHour_hour" name="" class="form-control select-time form-control">
        <option value="0">
          00
        </option>
        ........    
    </select>
</div
```

From java script I want to append and html before `div` with `class='time-widget'` :

```
$('<div>hello</div>').appendTo('#p_h_'+i+'_startHour_hour').parent();
```

But this html is adding to the select box not in front of `time-widget` div. Any suggestions ?Thx in advance.

Comment: try `$('<div>hello</div>').appendTo($('#p_h_'+i+'_startHour_hour').parent());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$('<div>hello</div>').appendTo('#p_h_'+i+'_startHour_hour').parent();` to `$('<div>hello</div>').insertBefore($('#p_h_'+i+'_startHour_hour').parent());`

You have to append it to an element.

**demo**

```js
$('<div>hello</div>').insertBefore($('#p_h_0_startHour_hour').parent());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="time-widget">
  <select id="p_h_0_startHour_hour" name="" class="form-control select-time form-control">
    <option value="0">
      00
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**demo 2**

```js
$('.test').remove();
$('<div class="test">hello</div>').insertBefore($('#p_h_0_startHour_hour').parent());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="time-widget">
  <select id="p_h_0_startHour_hour" name="" class="form-control select-time form-control">
    <option value="0">
      00
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: It's possible to remove html added before each `insertBefore`. Because it's added at each call and I have a lot of hello, but the ide is to have one. Thank you

Comment: So you want to remove the `<div>hello</div>` before you run the code?

Comment: yes, because actually now I call this code when submit a form and if the form has errors a do this insertBefore, so if I click multiple times on submit the div with hello is added multiple timees

Comment: try look at example 2

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to insert BEFORE `$('#p_h_'+i+'_startHour_hour')` because `'#p_h_'+i+'_startHour_hour'` is just a text, you forgot to put the `$` and to say you want it to be BEFORE (use `insertBefore()`)

```js
var i = 0;
$('<div>hello</div>').insertBefore(($('#p_h_'+i+'_startHour_hour').parent()));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="time-widget">
    <select id="p_h_0_startHour_hour" name="" class="form-control select-time form-control">
        <option value="0">
          00
        </option>
        ........    
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [insertbefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/)

```js
$('<div>hello</div>').insertBefore('.time-widget');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="time-widget">
  <select id="p_h_0_startHour_hour" name="" class="form-control select-time form-control">
    <option value="0"> 00</option>
  </select>
</div>
```